# How to save the terminal screen output in piping command

Tags: bash

I have few commands that I'm piping. The first command gives a big file output, while its output on the screen is only a very short statistical summary of it. The big file output is being processed fine through the piping, but I'd like to save the screen output into a text file, so my question is how to do it within the piping?

So far I've tried using `tee` the below:

```
&> someFile.txt
> someFile.txt
>> someFile.txt
```

But all of them gave me the big file output, but I'd like only the screen short output.
Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Is the 'screen output' written to standard error?  If so, you'll need `2>someFile.txt` (space permitted between `>` and `s`).  If you also want to see it on the screen, you have to work harder.  It isn't clear where the big file output is going — apparently not the screen, so not standard output?  Maybe the `tee` command is relevant; you might find `... 2>&1 | tee someFile.txt` does what you want.  The setup is not clear to me yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the output of *command_to_refine_big_output* on stdout and in a file called *log* in the current directory, this works:

```
command_with_big_output | command_to_refine_big_output | tee log
```

Note that this only writes stdout to log file, if your want stderr to, you can do:

```
command_with_big_output | command_to_refine_big_output 2>&1 | tee log
```

or, if you want all output, errors include of the complete chain:

```
command_with_big_output 2>&1 | command_to_refine_big_output 2>&1 | tee log
```